# POST request <h:outputLink> in using JSF

Tags: jsf, http-post

How to fire a POST request using h:outputLink command in jsf?

Answer (score 2):

use `<h:commandLink>` instead.

See [the post for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink)

Comment: I found a link on SO that uses more less the same title as the link you posted (which was not well formatted). Update the link if it is not the one you meant.